# Ruby on Rails: No validation error when using rails models association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations

I'm using Ruby on Rails association to link the Store model to the Product model, using:

```
store has_many :products
product belongs_to :store
```

The only condition on the Product model, is the presence of a name:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

To create a new product, I use this code inside the `Products` controller, `create` method:

```
@store = Store.find_by_id session[:store_id]

if @store.products.create(:name => params[:name])
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "New product successfully created."
else
    redirect_to :back, :alert => "Can't create new product."
end
```

The problem, is that it works however the product name exists or not. I mean, in all cases, I have the "New product successfully created." message, even if the product name is empty.

I can't figure out where is the problem. Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

You should use another method to understand the saved record or not.

```
@store = Store.find_by_id session[:store_id]

product = @store.products.build(name: params[:name])

if product.save
  redirect_to :back, notice: "New product successfully created."
else
  redirect_to :back, alert: "Can't create new product."
end
```